# Update table B with content of table A?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, Table A:

```
sid, phone, ts
```

And Table B:

```
id, phone, sid(NULL), ts
```

I have written a PHP script to connect, query and read in the data, but am not sure how to edit the data.

What I essentially want to do is match tableB `phone` with tableA `phone` and if match then update tableB column `sid` which is `NULL` with tableA `sid`.

I am sure this can be done with `while` and `foreach` loop but am not exactly sure how.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Didn't you use mysql queries?

Comment: Simple `select` and `update` query can do this.

Comment: No, the script has to be run periodically, data is updated every few seconds

Comment: can you share what you have done till now??

Comment: hi terrance.. you want it to work automatically right? Automatically update the db.. please see my answer. That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to automatically update the db, then you should be using CRON job.

**Step 1 :** Copy paste the following in a separate php file  say, cron.php. Add the db connection part also. :

```
$query_table1 = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result_table1= msyql_query($query_table1);
while($row_table1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_table1)){
    $phone1 = $row_table1['phone'];
    $sid1 = $row_table1['sid'];

    $query_table2 =  "UPDATE table2 SET sid=$sid1 WHERE phone=$phone1";
    $result_table2= msyql_query($query_table2);
}
```

**Step 2** : Go to your host control panel and go to cron. In that add a new cron job.

If you need to execute the file every 1 min then, this would help the cause:

`* * * * * <command> #Runs every minute`

The basic syntax would be **time /path/to/command arg1 arg2**

[Link to Cpanel docs](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs)

Cheers

Comment: ;)... you should be more clear about what you need. i got this from your comment only. :).. if you had mentioned you need to update the db automatically, then you would have found solution much earlier.. Cheers..:)

Comment: Yea sorry about that.. =/

Answer (score 1):

You have to run this query:

```
update tableA, tableB set tableB.sid = tableA.sid where 
                 tableB.phone = tableA.phone
```